# Different proof's of Marten's theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I am referring to Marten's theorem on the dimension of $W_d^r $ as in ACGH p. 192 .  It seems to me that an even shorter proof can be given using Hopf's Theorem that  if  $\nu : A \otimes B \to C $ is any map of vector spaces  A,B,C that is injective on each factor separately (over k algebraically closed) that one has $\dim(\nu(A \otimes B) \geq \dim(A) + \dim(B) - 1 $ . This  can also be found on p. 108 of ACGH. It seems that Marten's result follows directly upon putting $ A = H^0(C,L), B = H^0(C, K_C \otimes L^{-1} \mbox{ and } C = H^0(K_C)$.  Does anyone have a reference in the literature for a proof along those lines  or perhaps am I making a silly mistake ?

Comment: what Hopf lemma do you refer to?

Comment: I've revised the question to include the statement of Hopf's Theorem, not Hopf's lemma as I originally wrote.